# How to "flatten" tensor product matrix in python?

Tags: python

I start with a 3x3 array `m`, and tensor product it with itself.

I get a 3x3 array of 3x3 arrays, but really I would like to get a 9x9 array:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1. , 0.5, 0. ], [0.5, 1. , 0.5], [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])
a = np.tensordot(m,m, axes=0)
```

I tried `a.reshape(9,9)` but it did not do what I wanted... any more ideas?

Comment: Why does `a.reshape` not do what you want? What's wrong with the 9x9-array resulting from this command?

Comment: I can see that that matrix is not the same one as I would get if I "flatten" m. For instance, the first row of `a` does not have three zeros at the end, while `m` does.

Comment: Could you write the 9x9 arrays that you were expecting for that input and the array that you get instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly the question but I think what you may want is:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1. , 0.5, 0. ], [0.5, 1. , 0.5], [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])
a = np.tensordot(m, m, axes=0)
a = a.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3)).reshape((9, 9))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1.   0.5  0.   0.5  0.25 0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.5  1.   0.5  0.25 0.5  0.25 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.5  1.   0.   0.25 0.5  0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.5  0.25 0.   1.   0.5  0.   0.5  0.25 0.  ]
 [0.25 0.5  0.25 0.5  1.   0.5  0.25 0.5  0.25]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.   0.5  1.   0.   0.25 0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.5  0.25 0.   1.   0.5  0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.25 0.5  0.25 0.5  1.   0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.25 0.5  0.   0.5  1.  ]]
```

Comment: YEs that's exaclty what I want thanks. Why did you have to do the tranpose thing at some weird axis?

Comment: I was trying to find an explanation I wrote in a similar question some time ago but couldn't find it... The idea is, if you just reshape the result, after the first row of the first "submatrix" you get the second row of the same submatrix, when instead you want the first row of the second submatrix. The transposing makes that when you finish the first row of the first submatrix you jump to the next submatrix instead of to the next row.

Comment: So, before tranposing, the dimensions order is: row of submats, column of submats, submat row, submat column. After transposing: row of submats, submat row, column of submats, submat column. So `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, `[0, 0, 0, 1]` and `[0, 0, 0, 2]` (which go to `[0,0]`, `[0, 1]` and `[0, 2]` in the result) is the first row of the first submatrix in both cases, but `[0, 0, 1, 0]`, `[0, 0, 1, 1]` and `[0, 0, 1, 2]` (which go to `[0, 3]`, `[0, 4]` and `[0, 5]` in the result) are the second row of the 1st submatrix in the first case and the first row of 2nd submatrix in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.kron`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) seems to be what you're looking for.

```py
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1. , 0.5, 0. ], [0.5, 1. , 0.5], [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])
print(np.kron(m,m))
```

Output:

```py
[[1.   0.5  0.   0.5  0.25 0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.5  1.   0.5  0.25 0.5  0.25 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.5  1.   0.   0.25 0.5  0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.5  0.25 0.   1.   0.5  0.   0.5  0.25 0.  ]
 [0.25 0.5  0.25 0.5  1.   0.5  0.25 0.5  0.25]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.   0.5  1.   0.   0.25 0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.5  0.25 0.   1.   0.5  0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.25 0.5  0.25 0.5  1.   0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.25 0.5  0.   0.5  1.  ]]
```